# vs code open workspace in explorer keybinding

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I open a workspace's folder in my operating system's explorer window (i.e. explorer.exe), by using a keybinding? I cannot seem to find it in the default keybindings options in vs code.

Comment: Search for "reveal" word.

Comment: This enforces me to open a file just to open the explorer. Even worse, if I have no files in the workspace, I need to create a file to have a file to open, to launch the explorer window.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+K` `R` is the key combination to REVEAL the file that is currently open in the editor in Explorer. I don't think that the root of the workspace directory is an option.